# How get object from s3 with vuejs and amplify?

Tags: vue.js, amazon-s3, frontend, aws-amplify

I am trying to get an object from **aws-s3** (a test file with dictionnary inside) with **Vue.js** and **Amplify** for a frontend project. I would like to see the content of the file on my interface.
I'm simply using **Amplify library** with this tag in my `component.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <amplify-s3-text text-key="file_name" />
</template>
```

I configured the file `aws-exports.js` like this:

```js
const awsconfig = {
    "aws_project_region": "eu-west-1",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "aws_cognito_region": "eu-west-1",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "eu-west-xxxxx",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "xxxxxxx",
    "oauth": {},
    "aws_user_files": 'enable',
    "aws_user_files_s3_bucket": 'bucket_name',
    "aws_user_files_s3_bucket_region": 'eu-west-1',
};


export default awsconfig;
```

I'm working on an EC2 instance so I use a **forwarded port** to view my app on **localhost**. 

But I can't see anything in my interface. The **error** on the console is:

```
axios-http-handler Error: Request failed with status code 403
```

I am using an existing backend, so I don't want to use amplify/CLI.
I didn't find anything more in the official documentation (https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/storage/s3-text/q/framework/vue).

How can I display **the content of this s3 file** on my interface ?

Comment: can you see that object in your browser with full url? Also is that object has right access rules? It's possibly a file access permission issue.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/tr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/

Comment: I can access to my file with aws cli so I think the file has the right permissions. I can see the url and I verified it. I think I have to add something in the tag like the headers ?